# How to use COUNT() with where in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, pivot

I have tables `pages (id, ...)` and `page_visits (id, page_id, is_subscribed)`

The `page_visits` table now has about 2 million rows per one page_id.

I need to create a query that will grab count of visits and subscriptions per one page. My query only grabs visits count now:

```
SELECT page_id, COUNT(page_id) AS visits
FROM `page_visits`
WHERE `page_id` in (1, 2)
GROUP BY `page_id`
```

But how to add here an `page_subscriptions` column in result that will contains count of rows where `is_subscriped = 1` per one page_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` ignores `null`s, so you could perform a `count` over a `case` expression:

```sql
SELECT   page_id, 
         COUNT(page_id) AS visits 
         COUNT(CASE is_subscribed WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS subscried_visits
FROM     page_visits
WHERE    page_id IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY page_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `count(*)` and group by `is_subscribed` as well...

```
select `page_id`, count(*) as visits, `is_subscribed` from `page_visits` group by `page_id`, `is_subscribed`
```

You will get 2 rows per page:

1. With count for subscribers
2. With count for not subscribers

**`count(*)` does not ignore nulls**

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
select page_id, count(*) visits, sum(is_subscribed) page_subscriptions
from page_visits
where page_id in (1, 2)
group by page_id
```

Rationale:

- I would expect `page_id` to not be nullable; if so, `count(*)` is more efficient than `count(page_id)`
- `is_subscribed` seems to be storing `0`/`1` values - so counting the number of `1`s is equivalent to suming the column; this is much more efficient than a conditional count